Why are logos not inline with each other?
So i have a list of client logos, and i used one of tailwinds components to list them on my website, it should have made everything inline, but for some reason the logos aren't. Even though they are all the same dimensions some logos appear bigger then others, and when i check on inspect element it shows the logos as boxes(everything in html is boxes lol) and the boxes are inline with each other but not the actual logos. It looks crooked as people would say.
I tried modifying the dimensions and seeing if that would help my case, but in fact that did NOT do anything, so i came here.
Here is the Client Component code if any of you are wondering:
import React from 'react'
import accentureLogo from '../assets/images/accenture.svg'
import open from '../assets/clients/open.svg'
import equi from '../assets/clients/equi.svg'
import mol from '../assets/clients/mol.svg'
import cox from '../assets/clients/cox.svg'

function Clients() {
  return (
    <div className='flex justify-center items-center text-center'>
      <section className="mt-28 flex justify-center items-center text-center">
        <div className="py-8 lg:py-16 mx-auto max-w-screen-xl px-4">
          <div className="flex flex-wrap justify-center items-center space-x-8 space-y-4 md:space-y-0 text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">
            <a href="#" className="flex justify-center items-center">
              <img className='h-9 object-contain hover:text-gray-900 dark:hover:text-white' src={mol} alt="MOL" />
            </a>
            <a href="#" className="flex justify-center items-center">
              <img className='h-9 object-contain hover:text-gray-900 dark:hover:text-white' src={open} alt="Open" />
            </a>
            <a href="#" className="flex justify-center items-center">
              <img className='h-9 object-contain hover:text-gray-900 dark:hover:text-white' src={accentureLogo} alt="Accenture" />
            </a>
            <a href="#" className="flex justify-center items-center">
              <img className='h-9 object-contain hover:text-gray-900 dark:hover:text-white' src={cox} alt="Cox" />
            </a>
            <a href="#" className="flex justify-center items-center">
              <img className='h-9 object-contain hover:text-gray-900 dark:hover:text-white' src={equi} alt="Equi" />
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Clients

And here is a screenshot of how it looks on my END
https://imgur.com/a/gPcNSME
Does anyone know the answer to why it does this?

Where is the screenshot?

idk why it didnt save i put it in but here it is: https://imgur.com/a/gPcNSME

Could it be because the positions of these images are different within the PNG files themselves?

You may need to do some photo editing to make your life easier. Looking at the photo reference, they look centered in terms of an overall image (top of ascender in relation to bottom of ascender, making baseline look off), however the x-height, ascenders and descenders seem to be throwing off the overall centering as a whole. It may be you need to adjust baseline on each one to find the look and feel you like. I have sometimes brought logos like this into PS and created a single image as editing placement is just easier in a layout program like PS.

Dropping Opentext and Equifax baseline lower to match that of the other three would help. Let those ascenders be ascenders... IMHO

This isn't a CSS issue, it's an image issue.  If you make all the logo images the same height, and then visually center the logo inside that height (in an image editor), then it'll look visually aligned on the page.  Here's an image that hopefully will clarify.  Again, do this in an image editor, your code is exactly what it should be already.


As you Used flex property and justify-center, you also used align-center.
If Not work use the margin y-axis auto.
I hope that works for you.

.logos {
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;
}
try this add this in CSS File and in div with flex add className - logos
